# Removing an entry from a geode replicated region

Tags: geode

I have observed some behavior where calling

```
 region.removeAll(Collection<Object> keys)
```

does not remove the entry from ALL the servers in a replicated region.  I  have observed this making the call from both a PROXY client and a CACHING_PROXY client.  I am currently reading through the code and noticed there are slight differences in Remove(), RemoveAll(), Destroy(), DestroyAll().

What is the recommended way to remove an entry from all servers in a replicated region?  What are the expected differences in behavior, if any, for remove(), removeAll() Destroy() and DestroyAll()?

Is there any difference in behavior when these are called from different client types?

Answer (score 0):

When development started on GemFire, we were trying to follow JSR-107, hence we have a "Region" rather than a `Map`, and the region has a "destroy" method. We then made the Region implement the `ConcurrentMap` interface, which has `remove()` and `removeAll()`. There should not be any difference between the two, if you are seeing any that should be considered a bug. Can you please file a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GEODE/issues/GEODE-4748?filter=allopenissues) with a reproducible example?
Also, going forward, I would recommend sticking to the ConcurrentMap interface, since the other methods may be deprecated.